# Can I use Ubuntu desktop for DNS server

Tags: dns

Excuse me,
I have a laptop installed Ubuntu desktop. If I want to use the name server (DNS) in this position, is that possible? Or should I reinstall Ubuntu server?

Comment: That should be posted in http://askubuntu.com/ -- I prefer Ubuntu Server for many reasons, but the desktop is the same Linux kernel and servers. Only when you boot it forces you to X11 (which I do not like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily install `unbound` or `bind9` package and serve DNS queries in your LAN.

However, it's a bit more involved to setup the networking so that all the DNS queries made from your applications are directed to the caching DNS server running in the same installation. I had to get rid of `NetworkManager` and install `wicd` instead for this purpose. `NetworkManager` uses `dnsmasq` package (which doesn't cache queries) and all DNS queries are directed to `127.0.1.1`, where `dnsmasq` listens for queries. `wicd` makes easy to set a static DNS pointing to `127.0.0.1`, which is the address in which `unbound` listens by default.

Note: of course it isn't impossible to keep the default `NetworkManager` and setup properly to direct queries to the caching name server running in the same machine. I just think it's easier with `wicd`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can!But Ubuntu desktop usually have installed many applications,it may not work very well.If it is convenient ,you'd better use Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* difference between server and desktop is - which packages are installed *by default* during distro installation. To use your computer as a DNS server your will have to  install package for the DNS server, like `apt-get install bind9`. For server,maybe it's preinstalled (I don't know). That's all.

As in andy answer, maybe other applications running on Desktop will use too many resources or make your system unstable, and thus you better don't use them. In this case too, if you remove all the GUI-related packages you practically turn "desktop" into "server".

*Disclaimer: I'm not an expert, I may be wrong.*